# Read json file using python

Tags: json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Team, i have my code working with dict in comments below. Now, i want to move that to file.json and read from there keeping the logic same. any hints how can i represent my comment section below in json and read it backin dictionary?

convert python dictionary to json file and read in python

```
'''
source_cidr_name = {
    'location1' : ("1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]),
    'location2' : ("2.2.2.2/32", [443])}
'''
source_cidr_name = {}
    with open('/Users/code/dev/whitelist.json') as jf:
    source_cidr_name = json.load(jf)
```

file.json looks below but i don't know how to represent my ports 22 and 443
    {
    "source_cidr_whitelist": {"key1": {"ip_subnet": "1.1.1.1/32"}, "key2": {"ip_subnet": "2.2.2.2/32"]}}}

Comment: Please mention your errors as well.

Comment: I have figured out the problem and answered it. Please check and let me know if you are still struggling or if my answer did not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSON** i.e. `JavaScript Object Notaion` does not support including single quotes `'` around strings and `(` or `)` arounf lists/arrays while using `json.loads()` to convert string representation to object (dictionary).

Using `json.dumps()` is okay with tuples/list, single/double quotes etc. as Python internally converts them in proper valid JSON. Mean to say it converts `(` `)` used to represent/surround tuples to `[` `]` and `'` used to represent/surround strings to `"`.

> My suggestion to get rid of this kind of problems

While dumping/writing data to JSON file use `json.dumps()` to create string from an existing Python objects like list/dictionary (JSON convertible).

After that if you will read the same at any point of time later, it would be easily converted to the real Python object list/dictionary etc. using `json.loads()` from strings or using `json.load()` from file like objects.

> An example which helped to figure out

```
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> d = {
...     'location1' : ("1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]),
...     'location2' : ("2.2.2.2/32", [443])}
>>> 
>>> s = json.dumps(d, indent=4)
>>> print(s)
{
    "location2": [
        "2.2.2.2/32", 
        [
            443
        ]
    ], 
    "location1": [
        "1.1.1.1/32", 
        [
            22, 
            443
        ]
    ]
}
>>> 
>>> new_d = json.loads(s)
>>>
>>> new_d
{u'location2': [u'2.2.2.2/32', [443]], u'location1': [u'1.1.1.1/32', [22, 443]]}
>>> 
>>> new_d['location2']
[u'2.2.2.2/32', [443]]
>>> 
>>> new_d['location1']
[u'1.1.1.1/32', [22, 443]]
>>> 
>>> new_d['location1'][0]
u'1.1.1.1/32'
>>> new_d['location1'][1]
[22, 443]
>>> 
>>> new_d['location1'][1][0]
22
>>> new_d['location1'][1][1]
443
>>> 
>>> # NEW (start from string)
... 
>>> s = '''{
...     'location1' : ("1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]),
...     'location2' : ("2.2.2.2/32", [443])}'''
>>> print(s)
{
    'location1' : ("1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]),
    'location2' : ("2.2.2.2/32", [443])}
>>>
```

> 1st try

```
>>> s = '''{'location1' : ["1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]],'location2' : ["2.2.2.2/32", [443]]}'''
>>> s
'{\'location1\' : ["1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]],\'location2\' : ["2.2.2.2/32", [443]]}'
>>> 
>>> print(s)
{'location1' : ["1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]],'location2' : ["2.2.2.2/32", [443]]}
>>> 
>>> d = json.loads(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
>>>
```

> 2nd try

```
>>> 
>>> s = '''{
...     "location1" : ("1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]),
...     "location2" : ("2.2.2.2/32", [443])}'''
>>> 
>>> d = json.loads(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>>> 
>>>
```

> Finally

```
>>> s = '''{
...     "location1" : ["1.1.1.1/32", [22, 443]],
...     "location2" : ["2.2.2.2/32", [443]]}'''
>>> 
>>> d = json.loads(s)
>>> d
{u'location2': [u'2.2.2.2/32', [443]], u'location1': [u'1.1.1.1/32', [22, 443]]}
>>> 
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
>>> 
>>> d['location2']
[u'2.2.2.2/32', [443]]
>>> 
>>> d['location2'][1][0]
443
>>>
```